# Passing php variable to javascript (cant get it working)

Tags: php, javascript, variables

I'm have a problem getting a php variable to my .js file and make it work.

This is my php function where I'm trying to pass the variable:

```
function java_scr_preview ($foto)
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'var pass_this_variable =  "'.$foto.'"'; 
    echo '</script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="ddimgtooltip.js">';
    echo '<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">';
    echo 'function Preview(url)';
    echo '{';
    echo "window.open(url,'_blank','location=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,width=500,height=700')";
    echo '}';
    echo '</SCRIPT>';
}
```

This is my whole php script (if needed)

```
<?php

    require ("auth.php");

    if (isset($_GET['cmd'])) 
        $cmd  = $_GET['cmd'];
    else 
        $cmd = "";

    switch ($cmd) {

        case "":
            html_open_std ();
            ingave_artikel ("", "", "", "");
            html_close ();
            break;

        case "search":
            html_open_std ();
            ingave_artikel ("", "", "", "");
            toon_banden ();
            html_close ();
            break;

        case "preview":
            $foto   = $_GET['foto'];
            toon_preview ($foto);
            break;
    }

#------------------------------------------------------------

function ingave_artikel ($art1, $art2, $art3, $errormelding)
{
    global $urlphp;
    global $urlcgi;
    global $ad;

    echo "<div id=\"invoeren\">";
    echo "<h1>Ingave bandenmaat</h1>\n";

    echo "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"?cmd=search\">\n";
    echo "<table border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"2\" cellpadding=\"2\">\n";

    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td>Breedte</td>\n";
    echo "<td>&nbsp</td>\n";
    echo "<td>Hoogte</td>\n";
    echo "<td>&nbsp</td>\n";
    echo "<td>Diameter</td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";

    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"art1\" value=\"" . $art1 . 
            "\" size=\"5\"></td>\n";
    echo "<td>/</td>\n";
    echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"art2\" value=\"" . $art2 . 
            "\" size=\"5\"></td>\n";
    echo "<td>x</td>\n";
    echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"art3\" value=\"" . $art3 . 
            "\" size=\"5\"></td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";

    if (! empty ($errormelding))
            echo "<tr><td colspan=\"5\"><font color=\"red\">" . 
                $errormelding . "</td></tr>\n";

    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td colspan=\"3\">\n";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Verwerk\">\n";
    echo "</td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";

    echo "</table>\n";
    echo "</form>\n";
    echo "</div>\n";

}

#------------------------------------------------------------

function toon_banden ()
{
    global $urlphp;
    global $urlcgi;
    global $gateway;

    java_scr_preview ();

    $art1 = trim($_POST["art1"]);
    $art2 = trim($_POST["art2"]);
    $art3 = trim($_POST["art3"]);

    if (empty ($art1)  || empty ($art3)) {
        ingave_artikel ($art1, $art2, $art3, 
                    "Alle velden ingeven s.v.p.");
        return (-1);
    }

        $f = open_url ($gateway . "?3," .  $art1 . $art2 . "R" . $art3);

    if ($f == NULL)
        return (-1);

    $t = 0;
    $ncol = 4;

    $ar = explode (PHP_EOL, $f);

    if (substr($ar[0],0,7) == "*ERROR*") {
                echo "<p>";
                echo "<h1>";
                echo "Gateway functions are disabled !" . "<br>";
                echo "</p>";
                return (-1);
    }

    foreach ($ar as $rec) {
            if ($rec == 0) {
        continue;
    }
                list ($sysnr,
                      $artikel,
                      $merk,
                      $rubriek,
                      $omschrijving,
                      $valuta,
                      $netto,
                      $bruto,
                      $beschikbaar,
                      $foto,
                      $draagvrm,
                      $levid,
                      $garpr,
                      $altpr,
                      $eancode) = explode ("\t", $rec);

        if ($sysnr == "*END*")
            break;

        if ($t == 0) {


                echo "<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>";
    echo "<tr><td align=center>";
            echo "<div id=\"uitkomst\">";
            echo "<h1>Overzicht beschikbare voorraad</h1>\n";
            echo "<table border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"2\" cellpadding=\"5\">\n";
            echo "<td><b>Merk</td>\n";
            echo "<td><b>Omschrijving</td>\n";
            echo "<td><b>LI/SI</td>\n";
            echo "<td align=\"right\"><b>Bruto</td>\n";
            echo "<td align=\"right\"><b>Netto " . $valuta . "</td>\n";
            echo "<td align=\"right\"><b>Beschikbaar</td>\n";
            echo "<td></td>\n";
        }

        ### klantprijs opslag 25 %

        $klantpr = $netto * 1.25;
        $klantpr_str = sprintf ("%7.2f", $klantpr);
        echo "<tr>\n";
        echo "<td>" . $merk . "</td>\n";
        echo "<td>" . $omschrijving . "</td>\n";
        echo "<td>" . $draagvrm . "</td>\n";
        echo "<td align=\"right\">" . $bruto . "</td>\n";
        echo "<td align=\"right\">" . $klantpr_str . "</td>\n";
        echo "<td align=\"right\">" . $beschikbaar . "</td>\n";
        if (empty ($foto))
            echo "<td></td>\n";
        else {
            echo "<td>";
            echo '<a rel="imgtip[2]" href="javascript:Preview';
            echo "('?cmd=preview&foto=$foto')";
            echo '">';
            echo "Foto";
            echo '</a>';
            echo "</td>\n";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
        $t++;
    }

    if ($t == 0)
        ingave_artikel ($art1, $art2, $art3, 
                    "Geen artikelen gevonden !");
    else {
        echo '</table>';
        echo '</div>';
    }

}

#------------------------------------------------------------

function toon_preview ($fotonr)
{
        global $imglarge;

        html_open_std ();
    echo '<center>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<img border="0" src="' . $imglarge . '/' . $fotonr . '">';
        html_close ();
}

#------------------------------------------------------------

function toon_selektie ($merk, $model, $type, $diameter)
{
    echo '<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">';
    echo '<tr><td width="70">Merk</td><td><b>' . $merk . '</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td>Model</td><td><b>' . $model . '</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td>Type</td><td><b>' . $type . '</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td>Diameter</td><td><b>' . $diameter . '</td></tr>';
    echo '</table>';
    echo '<hr>';
}

#------------------------------------------------------------

function open_url ($url)
{
    global $login;
    global $passwd;

    $ch = curl_init("http://$url");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$login:$passwd");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $file = curl_exec($ch);

    $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $errno = curl_errno($ch);
    $error = curl_error($ch);

    if ($status == 200) {
        return ($file);
    }
    else {
        echo "<p>";
        echo "<h1>";
        if ($status == 401) {
            echo "Authentication failed !";
        }
        else {
            echo "Errno: " . $errno . "<br>";
            echo "Error: " . $error . "<br>";
            echo "HTTP status : " . $status . "<br>";
        }
        echo "</p>";
        return (NULL);
    }
}

#------------------------------------------------------------

function html_open_std ()
{
    echo '<html>';
    echo '<head>';
    echo '<title>Banden uit voorraad leverbaar</title>';
    echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">';
    echo '<meta name="robots" content="noinclude, nofollow">';
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="tyre.css" type="text/css">';
    echo '</head>';
    echo '<body>';
}

#------------------------------------------------------------

function html_close ()
{
    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";
}

#------------------------------------------------------------

function java_scr_preview ($foto)
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'var pass_this_variable =  "'.$foto.'"'; 
    echo '</script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="ddimgtooltip.js">';
    echo '<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">';
    echo 'function Preview(url)';
    echo '{';
    echo "window.open(url,'_blank','location=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,width=500,height=700')";
    echo '}';
    echo '</SCRIPT>';
}
?>
```

And this is my whole .js file:

It is a tooltip script and I want to show my images dynamicly:

```
/* Image w/ description tooltip v2.0
* Created: April 23rd, 2010. This notice must stay intact for usage 
* Author: Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/
* Visit http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
*/


var ddimgtooltip={

    tiparray:function(){
        var tooltips=[]
        //define each tooltip below: tooltip[inc]=['path_to_image', 'optional desc', optional_CSS_object]
        //For desc parameter, backslash any special characters inside your text such as apotrophes ('). Example: "I\'m the king of the world"
        //For CSS object, follow the syntax: {property1:"cssvalue1", property2:"cssvalue2", etc}

        tooltips[0]=["red_balloon.gif", "Here is a red balloon<br /> on a white background", {background:"#FFFFFF", color:"black", border:"5px ridge darkblue"}]
        tooltips[1]=["duck2.gif", "Here is a duck on a light blue background.", {background:"#DDECFF", width:"200px"}]
        tooltips[2]=["http://www.website.net/preview/test/pass_this_variable"]
        tooltips[3]=["../dynamicindex17/bridge.gif", "Bridge to somewhere.", {background:"white", font:"bold 12px Arial"}]

        return tooltips //do not remove/change this line
    }(),

    tooltipoffsets: [20, -30], //additional x and y offset from mouse cursor for tooltips

    //***** NO NEED TO EDIT BEYOND HERE

    tipprefix: 'imgtip', //tooltip ID prefixes

    createtip:function($, tipid, tipinfo){
        if ($('#'+tipid).length==0){ //if this tooltip doesn't exist yet
            return $('<div id="' + tipid + '" class="ddimgtooltip" />').html(
                '<div style="text-align:center"><img src="' + tipinfo[0] + '" /></div>'
                + ((tipinfo[1])? '<div style="text-align:left; margin-top:5px">'+tipinfo[1]+'</div>' : '')
                )
            .css(tipinfo[2] || {})
            .appendTo(document.body)
        }
        return null
    },

    positiontooltip:function($, $tooltip, e){
        var x=e.pageX+this.tooltipoffsets[0], y=e.pageY+this.tooltipoffsets[1]
        var tipw=$tooltip.outerWidth(), tiph=$tooltip.outerHeight(), 
        x=(x+tipw>$(document).scrollLeft()+$(window).width())? x-tipw-(ddimgtooltip.tooltipoffsets[0]*2) : x
        y=(y+tiph>$(document).scrollTop()+$(window).height())? $(document).scrollTop()+$(window).height()-tiph-10 : y
        $tooltip.css({left:x, top:y})
    },

    showbox:function($, $tooltip, e){
        $tooltip.show()
        this.positiontooltip($, $tooltip, e)
    },

    hidebox:function($, $tooltip){
        $tooltip.hide()
    },


    init:function(targetselector){
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            var tiparray=ddimgtooltip.tiparray
            var $targets=$(targetselector)
            if ($targets.length==0)
                return
            var tipids=[]
            $targets.each(function(){
                var $target=$(this)
                $target.attr('rel').match(/\[(\d+)\]/) //match d of attribute rel="imgtip[d]"
                var tipsuffix=parseInt(RegExp.$1) //get d as integer
                var tipid=this._tipid=ddimgtooltip.tipprefix+tipsuffix //construct this tip's ID value and remember it
                var $tooltip=ddimgtooltip.createtip($, tipid, tiparray[tipsuffix])
                $target.mouseenter(function(e){
                    var $tooltip=$("#"+this._tipid)
                    ddimgtooltip.showbox($, $tooltip, e)
                })
                $target.mouseleave(function(e){
                    var $tooltip=$("#"+this._tipid)
                    ddimgtooltip.hidebox($, $tooltip)
                })
                $target.mousemove(function(e){
                    var $tooltip=$("#"+this._tipid)
                    ddimgtooltip.positiontooltip($, $tooltip, e)
                })
                if ($tooltip){ //add mouseenter to this tooltip (only if event hasn't already been added)
                    $tooltip.mouseenter(function(){
                        ddimgtooltip.hidebox($, $(this))
                    })
                }
            })

        }) //end dom ready
    }
}

//ddimgtooltip.init("targetElementSelector")
ddimgtooltip.init("*[rel^=imgtip]")
```

And this rule:

```
tooltips[2]=["http://www.website.net/preview/test/pass_this_variable"]
```

Should show the variable $foto...

Anyone can help me to fix this? Working 2 days on it now and cant figure it out...

**Update**

I've tried some things and I manage to get some info to my javascript like this:

.php file

```
function java_scr_preview ()
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>';
?>

<?php
$foto = "image.jpg";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var foto = "<?= $foto ?>";
</script>
<?php

    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="ddimgtooltip.js">';
    echo '<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">';
    echo 'function Preview(url)';
    echo '{';
    echo "window.open(url,'_blank','location=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,width=500,height=700')";
    echo '}';
    echo '</SCRIPT>';
}
?>
```

.js file

```
tooltips[2]=["http://www.website.net/preview/test/"+ foto];
alert(tooltips[2]);
```

This is showing http://www.website.net/preview/test/image.jpg in my alert...

But when I'm doing it like this:

```
$foto = $_GET["foto"];
```

I'm getting an error :

Notice: Undefined index: foto in /var/www/html/website.nl/test/test.php on line 291

And in my alert only http://www.website.net/preview/test/...

How should I pass my dynamic variable?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
tooltips[2]=["http://www.website.net/preview/test/pass_this_variable"]
```

to

```
tooltips[2]=["http://www.website.net/preview/test/" + pass_this_variable]
```

You were not using the variable you were just passing text.

[Simplified example here](http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/mJr3b/)

Answer (score 0):

In function **toon_banden()** you call **java_scr_preview()** and you are not passing the expected arg.

Comment: The OP doesn't need to pass the variable as its global

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: foto in /var/www/html/website.nl/test/test.php on line 88

Line 88: java_scr_preview ($foto);

And With My old code I did get a broken image when I hover it...

And With changing this: tooltips[2]=["http://www.website.net/preview/test/" + pass_this_variable]

It does nothing at all

Comment: The tooltip script and the "pass_this_variable" are included when is executed the function **java_scr_preview**. But, in your switch, this function is only executed in the **search** case. So, in the other cases they will not be included. Try to check this.

Comment: If the url http://www.website.net/preview/test/image.jpg must show the **image.jpg**, so $_GET['foto'] should work, instead of $_POST['foto'] , because you're using a GET request.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply... I made a mistak... I used GET but forgot to change it...